# How to Start automatically cloud9 ide on server startup

Tags: startup, boot, bootloader, cloud9-ide

we start cloud9 ide on terminal open to global by running

/usr/local/cloud9/bin/cloud9.sh -l 0.0.0.0 -w /root/workspace --username xxxx --password yyyy

this runs the port but when terminal is closed the app closes.. how to keep it running or how to make the app start and be ready on automatically..

Comment: After hours of putting them here and there.. putting these lines in rc.local worked...    source /usr/local/nvm/nvm.sh
nvm use v0.10.22
/usr/local/cloud9/bin/cloud9.sh -l 0.0.0.0 -w /root/workspace --username xxxx --password yyyy

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **linux os** that you can copy and paste this command into `/etc/init.d/rc.local.sh` this file. So, whenever you are rebooting your machine at that time this command will execute.

And you have use `&&` this **double and symbol** of end the command so even if you close the terminal also the app will work.

And, if you want to stop the node process  excute this command `ps -e|grep node` and you'll get the node process ID and execute `Kill processid` command to stop the app.